# Best practice to get access to existing function in C?

Tags: c, function, prototype

Say I'm working on a large project and I need access to a function, foo(), in a source file named example.c. The prototype for foo() is declared in example.c as well. example.c has no header specific to this file, such as example.h. What is the best practice to get access to example.c's foo() from the new source file that I'm working on?

Comment: Make your own prototype?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, isn't it one of the worst practices?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If there is no header file which declares the function the function is probably not meant to be used as an interface. It is only meant for usage withing the translation unit where it is declared.

1. Check and confirm why does the design does not expose it as an interface.
2. Once you confirm #1, and see no problems about it being used through external TU's then add the function declaration in a header file. Include the header file in TU which used it to begin with and also include the header in TU which wants to use this function.

Answer (score 0):

Provided that example.c contains no main() function, you can just do

```
#include <example.c>
```

for your code to access foo() inside the file :)

Comment: Forgive me whoever downvoted, but I beg to differ that you can do that. If you still don't believe me, I can show you a working example:)

Comment: Including `.c` files is very rarely a good idea. It's an easy way to get duplicate definitions.

Comment: Won't that incur linking errors if those functions depend on external definitions? And what if that `.c` file depends on a header file?

Comment: The question was whether or not he could access the function inside the .c file, of course if it is a dependant c file, made working, it stands to reason that the requisite header files will be included in it. Otherwise, you can go straight ahead and use a general c file :)

Comment: Yes, and what if the contents of the header file conflict with symbols defined in the file? And what about linking?

Comment: If we don't know the symbols in the header files we include, we don't use the header until we have studied it. When the file is available with us, we can study the file `example.c` and see which symbols can cause conflict. And what is the problem with linking? We can use #include <absolute_path_to/example.c>, and it will work, or we can copy the file to the include folder if gcc, and directly reference it as `<example.c>`. We used to do this in uni, when we were learning our way around the header files :) I came across this trick accidently, when I renamed my file as .c instead of .h

Comment: If you can do something in C, it doesn't mean you should. Note the "best practices" in the question. Including a .c file was never a good practice to get access to function definitions.